# Dynamic body andkinematic body collision

Tags: box2d, collision

How do I make dynamic body not collidable with kinematic body. I still want to check if there would be a collision but dynamic body should move trough him upon collision. (And i also like to make kinematic body invisible with debug draw;is that possible)

Answer (score 0):

You can set `isSenor()` to `true` for kinematic body.

```
bodyDef.isSensor = true;
```

> set `isSensor()` to `true` when you want to know when objects will
>   collide without triggering a collision response.